# Create a new ArrayList with all the elements of another ArrayList except one in one line of code

Tags: java, optimization, arraylist

I would love to do this in one line:

```
ArrayList<Integer> newArray = new ArrayList<>(oldArray);
newArray.remove(0);
function(newArray);
```

I have tried this:

```
function(new ArrayList<>(oldArray.remove(0));
```

But it does not work. Is it possible? Any suggestion?

Comment: I am curious why this is tagged with `optimization`, what are you really optimising? The use of disk space?

Comment: Yes. This is part of an algorithm that may highly benefit from a saving like this

Comment: I find that hard to believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `subList`:

```
function(new ArrayList<>(oldArray.subList(1, oldArray.size())));
```

That will create a new `ArrayList` initialized with all elements in `oldArray` except the first one.

Answer (score 1):

In java 8 you can do this:

```
function(oldArray.stream().skip(1).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

If you need an `ArrayList` use this:

```
function(oldArray.stream().skip(1).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
```

Comment: Why are you doing new ArrayList when toList creates a new list?

Comment: If the OP really needs an `ArrayList`, then `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<Integer>::new))` will be approapriate.

Answer (score 1):

To program by interface that is a good practice favor `List` over `ArrayList` as parameter of  your `function()` method.

You could so do it :

```
function(oldArray.stream().skip(1).collect(toList());
```

If you really need to use a specific `List` implementation you can still do :

```
function(oldArray.stream().skip(1).collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```